# WordPress: Why my amp pages are not coming up in google search?

Tags: wordpress, html, web, content-management-system, amp-html

I have added amp pages to my WordPress website using [AMP for WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/) Plugin. There are total 5 Pages and 1 blog post on my website but none of them are coming up in google search.

Google search console shows 17 pages and 4 amp pages are indexed. There is no crawler issue or robots.txt issue. So, why they are not showing in google search even after 10 days.

My Website: https://www.hsourcetech.com/

Amp pages on my website:

https://www.hsourcetech.com/sap-training-in-btm/amp/

https://www.hsourcetech.com/about-us/amp/

https://www.hsourcetech.com/services/amp/

https://www.hsourcetech.com/trainings/amp/

Comment: From review: *"So, why they are not showing in google search even after 10 days."* Seems very broad. Please specify. (skipped review)

Comment: So, what else do you need for review? Tell me, I can help you.

Comment: It just seems unclear what exactly you are encountering. Do you have some sort of google backend account, where you can see that your pages are not added to the search results? Or do you search for your pages on google and can not find them? How do you measure "Not showing on google search"? Based on that it could be a technical problem or just a problem with the wrong keywords for example.

Comment: I am checking the indexing statistics on Google Webmaster Tools. Its showing 17 normal pages and 4 amp pages are indexed. But when I search for the keyword "sap training in btm" or even for the website "H Source Technologies", none of the pages are coming in google search.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://imgur.com/a/Tq0YL). I searched for "H Source Technologies"

Comment: When you searched - "H Source Technologies" from your mobile, did you saw any amp page of this website in SERP?